# __autoload and including files

Tags: php

I have a site which uses the library file `lib.client.php` which is stored in the `php` folder in my standard website root and contains a series of classes I have built.

I am going to have to `require_once` this library file in almost every single page, what is the best way I can implement this? Furthermore, should I be using some conbination of functions using `__autoload` to accomplish this?

Having seen a very similar question which touches on the issue but offers a very specific answer I can't really use, and looking a bit into the `__autoload` function, I want to get a more detailed answer for my requirements.

Comment: Autoloaders only make sense for loading classes. Commonly there is a 1:1 mapping between classes and files. Otherwise you need an intelligent resolver with class-file map/cache. If you have a functions-only include script, it's not an option.

Comment: So would you advise I break up my file?

Comment: If it works, why change it? And if the code base is small enough to warrent keeping it coherent, then no. But your `__autoload` would then just need to `require_once` that one file, else fail for unkown classes. That's more code than simply using that require_once by itself.

Comment: I have broken up my files because having about 20 classes in 1 document was a bit hard to use. I now have 20 different php files spread throughout my php folder in two sub-folders, one for 'client' classes and one for 'ulility' classes. How do I now make use of the autoload function with these files (aka where would it be implemented)?

Answer (score 1):

You use __autoload (or better: spl_autoload_register; or even better: some autoloader written by someone else) if:

- you have many classes that are being used in different order in different files;
- classes are spread across many files;
- there is a strict way to tell which class is in which file.

In your case: just use require_once (or refactor, but I would not bother).

Comment: Whats the main reason for using `spl_autoload_register` over `__autoload`?

Comment: you can spl_autoload_register many functions and you can only have one __autoload. Using raw __autoload might crash with some libraries that have their own autoloading schemes.